# Test class fails after adding another class

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I am calling 2 classes (class1 and class2) from trigger on an update operation. Class1 is completely developed with unit tests and everything. Now I have written class2 on the same trigger update Class2 development is done and is working as expeceted but not yet written any test class.

After I moved my class2 code into sandbox (with out test class yet), my test class for class1 is failing. Does that mean anything wrong with class 2 ? or is it because I havent yet written any test class for class2.

I am using JSONGenerator in class2 and in the debug log for class1, I am getting "null argument for jsongenerator.writestringfield()"

**my class (class 2)**

```
public withsharingclass caseTrigger {

    public class fetchInit{
        public list<case> caseRecord = new list<case>([Select ..... From Case Where ID IN :trigger.new]);        
        Case[] caseQueryUser = New Case[]{};
        Case[] caseQueryQueue = New Case[]{};
    }

//trigger calls this class on case insert
    public void caseInsert(list<case> caseList){
        caseList = f.caseRecord;
        if(caseList.size() > 0){
            for(case c : caseList){
                if(c.Status != 'closed' && c.owner.type == 'Queue'){
                    f.caseQueryQueue.add(c);
                }           
            }
            if(f.caseQueryQueue.size()>0){postCases_Queue(JSON.serialize(f.caseQueryQueue));}
        }
    }

    public static string IdSplit(Id i){
        string s = i+'';
        return s.substring(0,s.length()-3);
    }

    @future(callout = true)
    public static void postCases_Queue (string caseList){
        Case[] queueCases = (Case[])JSON.deserialize(caseList,List<Case>.class);
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartArray();        
        for(case c: queueCases) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('caseId', IdSplit(c.Id));
            gen.writeStringField('Queue', c.owner.name);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }   
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without posting your code it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: A missing test will not cause any problem in non-test code. But writing the test for class2 and running both tests may help you diagnose the problem. One of the purposes of tests is to make sure the code works under a variety of conditions.

Comment: class1 - has test class (test_class1 with status pass), class 2 is just developed as per requirement with no test class. When added class2 to sandbox, functionality is as per requirement but when I ran all tests in developer console, test_class1 is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error in test class 1 (that previously passed) is because you hooked your trigger into class 2 now. Class 2 is throwing the error and thus causing the previous test to fail.....

The only way to resolve it would be to fix the error is class 2. It does not mean the test class 1 is bad it just means that the code is class 2 is not working properly..

Without your code, there is no other way we can help....

Comment: Hi Eric.. I added my class. Please suggest me any corrections. Class by itself is working fine with no errors.

Comment: @pmvsdt - Where is the error coming from. I do not see any line with `jsongenerator.writestringfield()` honestly, the error is pretty self explanatory. Something is null that cannot be. Use the debug console to find it and then figure out why it is null. We would need your trigger code also.

Comment: @pmvsdt - Since this made you ask this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87519/write-if-condition-for-stringfields-in-json-generator can you please mark it as solved so it does not keep surfacing? (unless you feel it is not solved, but your other question is marked as solved so...)