# Write if condition for stringfields in JSON Generator

Tags: unit-test, json

There are group of fields I am querying and putting them in JSON. Some of these fields may be blank which is making previous test classes fail throwing a nul pointer exception.

**Present Code **  There are many other fields. I am just putting a sample

```
        gen.writeStringField('DayPhone', c.contact.OtherPhone);
        gen.writeStringField('EveningPhone', c.contact.HomePhone);
        gen.writeStringField('WorkPhone', c.contact.phone), c.account.Billing_Account_Number__c);
```

Currently, I have to write if condition like this for it to work:

```
    if(c.contact.HomePhone != null){gen.writeStringField('EveningPhone', c.contact.HomePhone);}
    if(c.contact.phone != null){gen.writeStringField('WorkPhone', c.contact.phone);}
    if(c.contact.MobilePhone != null){gen.writeStringField('Mobile', c.contact.MobilePhone);}
```

Since I am adding if on every line, I wanted to know if any check can be done all at once or any other option.

**Update **
I found that using JSON serialize can avoid this exception. So I am planning to change my code from JSON Generator to serialize instead of writing if condition on all fields. But is there a way to add if condition while serializing.

Ex: When I use JSONGenerator I can add if condition like this:

```
if(c.accountId != null){ gen.writestringfield(c.accountId); }
```

which adds this value to json only if accountid is not null. But in case of serialize, it is

```
public class caseVars {
           public string caseId;
        public string accountId;
}

public static void postCases (list<case> c1) {
   for(case c: c1){
            caseVars caseVar = new caseVars();
            caseVar.caseId = IdSplit(c.Id); 
     if(c.accountId != null){ caseVar.accountId = c.accountId; }
}
```

I believe in the second method, evenif accountId is null, there is a label named accountId with null value in the Jsonstring. Is there a way to control that ? ( Is there a way not to show accountId field at all in JSON string if there is no accountId on case)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to have a map of the API fields on the contact record to their corresponding key values for your JSON string. Then you could put your Contact record into an sObject variable and use the `.get` method to dynamically retrieve a field value based on the API name:

```
sObject contactSObject = c.contact;

Map <String, String> fieldNames = new Map <String, String> ('HomePhone' => 'EveningPhone', 'Phone' => 'WorkPhone', 'MobilePhone' => 'Mobile');

for (String fieldName : fieldNames.keySet())
{
    if (contactSObject.get(fieldName) != null)
    {
        gen.writeStringField(fieldNames.get(fieldName), (String)contactSObject.get(fieldName));
    }
}
```

Be careful with the types as not all fields return `String`. I'll leave that to you to sort out.

Comment: Thansk Bachovski... Another option I found is when I use serialize instead of JSONGenerator, I am not getting the null exception. May be I have to change my entire code as there are fields other than contacts also...

Comment: Yeah that's another option, you could serialize the object and the run a replace method on the string

Comment: Thanks Bachovski, I am trying to change to serialize. Is there a way to ontrol the fields in json string when using serialize ? (updated code in the question)

Comment: Unfortunately no - you can't control the fields when you use the `serialize` method. You need to run some regex on the output string in order to remove them. A good example can be found here - https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/stripping-nulls-from-a-json-object-in-apex/